# How to delete images from a directory in android

Tags: android

**I Created a Image at the location. And I can see The Image got created**

```
String Dirlocation = "Pictures/MyDirectoryName";
String mImageName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

createFile(mDirectoryPath,mImageName,fileData);

private String createFile(String mDirectoryPath, String mImageName, byte[] fileData) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream out=null;
        try{
            File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mDirectoryPath);
            File dir = new File(root + File.separator);
            if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();

            //Create file..
            String mFinalUri = root + File.separator + mImageName;
            File file = new File(mFinalUri);
            file.createNewFile();

            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            if(out!=null){
                out.write(fileData);
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpg" }, null);
            }

            //Check if file exists if true return the URI
            File mFile = new File(mFinalUri);
            if(mFile.exists()){
                return mFinalUri;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }

        return mDirectoryPath;
    }
```

---

**How to delete all the images in that directory ?**

***I tried with:***

```
String mDirectoryPath = "Pictures/MyDirectoryName";
            File dir = new File(mDirectoryPath);
            if (dir.isDirectory())
            {
                String[] children = dir.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                {
                    new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                }
            }
```

---

- Images inside the directory is not getting deleted
- `dir.isDirectory()` is failing and saying its not a directory

***How to Delete images properly ?***

Comment: in the delete part shouldn't you be using something like `File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mDirectoryPath)`

Comment: @Blackbelt ....  Damm I forgot ;) .... Can you please post as answer so i can accept it

Comment: check these permission in manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delete code you should be using

`File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mDirectoryPath)`

And not

`File dir = new File(mDirectoryPath);`.

In your code the file will point to "/Pictures/MyDirectoryName"; which doesn't exist (your app doesn't have permission to write on the root /)